# Is there a way to constantly update a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make this thing where in one tab you type something, and in another it pops up. However, I have to constantly reload the page to get my next message. First, this is what I tried.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="message"></p>
    <script>
        var x = localStorage.getItem('message')
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5) {
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = x;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

HOWEVER, this puts the page in a constant reloading state. How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) would help you.

Comment: You can use `setInterval` to check for a change in localStorage periodically.

Comment: You can also receive messages from the server using Web Sockets or server-side events.

Comment: @blex Put that in an answer, it's better than my `setInterval` answer.

Comment: Yor `for` loop will never be done = infinite loop:
`for (i = 0; i < 5) {
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = x;
        }`

Comment: `for` loops must have three mandatory blocks, separated by semi-colons `;`. Firefox says this about your code: `SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop condition`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setInterval` instead of a loop.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var x = localStorage.getItem('message');
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = x;
}, 1000);
```

This will update every second.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of constantly polling for updates, you can set up an event listenener to catch every message that is sent. You can do this thanks to the [`storage` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event):

```
// Every time a change it made to this domain's localStorage (item added, changed, removed)
window.addEventListener('storage', function() {
  // Update your DOM 
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('message');     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop.  A for loop has four steps.

- Initialization: Declaring the variable and its initial value(Happens
  once)
- Condition: Checking the condition to continue the loop
- Final
- Expression: Usually where you handle your logic that will end your
  loop like incrementing the i variable
- Execution: Execute the code in the code block

Your method is working but it never stops working, hence why your browser doesn't stop loading.

The for loop moves too quickly anyway and it would be better to put to listen for a storage event update on your document.

```
var messageContainer = document.querySelector('#message')

window.addEventListener('storage', function() {
var text = localStorage.getItem('message')
messageContainer.textContent = text
}
```